# ESB 2.2 EsbImportUtil.exe The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Configuration.ConfigHelper' throw exception

Tags: biztalk-deployment

when importing the itineries using `ESB 2.2 EsbImportUtil.exe` following error is displayed
I have `EnterpriseLibrary 5` installed and GAC contain `EnterpriseLibrary 4.1 dll` also.

The type initializer for '`Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Configuration.ConfigHelper`' threw an exception.`[A]Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceSection cannot be cast to [B]Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceSection. Type A originates from 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common\5.0.414.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll'. Type B originates from 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common\4.1.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll'.`

Thanks for the help

Comment: I've hit the same problem, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made any changes to `esb.config` file. Added new orchestation, try removing it. I had similar issue; fixed by removing wrong configuration.

Check:-
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bf2446fd-87fb-462a-8b78-cde7026bfdf5/the-type-initialize-for-microsoftpracticesesbconfigurationconfighelper-threw-an-exception?forum=biztalkesb